# Grub disappeared

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I run Endeavour OS and just installed Lubuntu as a secondary/dual boot OS. During the installation it said it would install the boot loader on the same partition as the existing one. After installing and rebooting, the "old" Grub menu (from when I only had Endeavour) appeared, and I booted into Endeavour to run `grub-mkconfig` to generate the config. However, both `grub-mkconfig`and `update-grub` have disappeared, and my /boot directory only contains a file called intel-ucode.img. I've never experienced this before, and I've installed multiple OS's many times before.

I guess I could just reinstall both grub-mkconfig and update-grub, but I'm also interested in what has actually happened. Why have they disappeared, and why is /boot empty? And would reinstalling them be the right solution?